# Modify jquery to not open the image when click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have found this script that expand image when mouse is over, but when click the image, open the image in a new page.

I would like modify the script because I don't want that image open in new page when click.

How  I can modify the script to not open the photo in new page?

This is the script:

```
this.imagePreview = function(){ 
    /* CONFIG */

        xOffset = 10;
        yOffset = 30;

        // these 2 variable determine popup's distance from the cursor
        // you might want to adjust to get the right result

    /* END CONFIG */
    $("a.preview").hover(function(e){
        this.t = this.title;
        this.title = "";    
        var c = (this.t != "") ? "<br/>" + this.t : "";
        $("body").append("<p id='preview'><img src='"+ this.href +"' alt='Image preview' />"+ c +"</p>");                                
        $("#preview")
            .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
            .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
            .fadeIn("fast");                        
    },
    function(){
        this.title = this.t;    
        $("#preview").remove();
    }); 
    $("a.preview").mousemove(function(e){
        $("#preview")
            .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
            .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
    });         
};


// starting the script on page load
$(document).ready(function(){
    imagePreview();
});
```

To see the demo: http://cssglobe.com/lab/tooltip/02/

Thanks

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('a.preview').click({
    function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

To have all previews to occur at the same position, change the coordinates in these lines

```
.css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
.css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
```

Write the coordinate that you want in place of `e.pageY - xOffset` and `e.pageX + yOffset`

Comment: And is possible that all photo expand in the same position of page? and not a relative position with mouse?

Answer (score 2):

The `.preventDefault()` function will do this for you:

```
$("a.preview").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Ah ok Thanks!!! And is possible that all photo expand in the same position of page? and not a relative position with mouse?

Comment: Yes, but you should probably create a new question on this issue and not mix it with this one. Keeping each question as specific as possible =)